# Switching WSO2 API Manager Endpoints for Multiple Environments

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**How to bulk move configured APIs to another environment in WSO2 API Manager Publisher?**

I am working with WSO2 API Manager, and my application has multiple environments. In the WSO2 API Manager Publisher, I have configured endpoints for one environment. However, I need to move these configurations to another environment for a bulk of APIs.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this in WSO2 API Manager Publisher? What steps or configurations should I follow to efficiently switch the endpoints for a group of configured APIs to a different environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [API Controller](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/) for this. Using the controller you can easily export and import APIs across environments. While importing you can change environment-specific parameters of the APIs. Take a look at [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/managing-apis-api-products/migrating-apis-to-different-environments/) and [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/advanced-topics/configuring-environment-specific-parameters/#defining-the-params-file-for-an-api) documents.